# Buildnumber maven plugin returns null in the mean time of jar creation

Tags: java, maven, svn

I am trying to write SVN revision number to MANIFEST.MF. I added maven build number plug in, scm connection properties to pom. My build number returns null.After when I define revisionOnScmFailure then it return test. I am using Collabnet Subversion Edge 1.3.3

Some guys  say that you have to install  SVN client. Tortoise SVN is installed on my computer. And it is define in Path System variable.Also it is not a new project.

I have also  added username and password, tried them when connecting to scm connection

```
<scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:https://remoteip/svn/trunk/psa</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://remoteip/svn/trunk/psa</developerConnection>
</scm>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>create</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <doCheck>false</doCheck>
                <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
                <username>username</username>
                <password>password</password>
                <revisionOnScmFailure>"test"</revisionOnScmFailure>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Make this jar executable -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.lib.path}</outputDirectory>
                        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>${project.lib.path}/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>client.gui.MainGuiFrame</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Implementation-Build>${buildNumber}</Implementation-Build>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: If you haven't installed the svn command line client either separately or with newer versions of TortoiseSVN this will not work. You can solve this also by using an approriate provider (Example: https://gist.github.com/Riduidel/2966608).

Comment: Adding dependency is not sufficient as I know.i remember that  I tried it.so do I have to also install svn command line client?